# Time Zone API response - meaning of field rawOffset

Tags: google-maps

i thought rawOffset "raw" data that does not affected by timestamp parameter when calling Google Map Time Zone API. but things is a little confusion and hope someone can help:

I query time zone info on EDINBURGH: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=55.9066276551,-3.2620390298&timestamp=1431545430&key=[KEY]

1431545430 represent today's time in second. And i got response that has dstOffset=3600 and rawOffset=0

Then query the same location for time zone info but set timestamp=0 (it is not in day time saving, i believe):
     https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=55.9066276551,-3.2620390298&timestamp=0&key=[KEY]

Then i got dstOffset=0 and rawOffset=3600

you can see rawOffset is changed to 3600 from 0. is it possible EDINBURGH time zone is reconfigured since 1970 so zone is changed to 0 to 1?

I did same test on BOSTON in bot cases it returns rawOffset=-18000 and dstOffset=3600 if timestamp = current time (summer time at Boston) or dstOffset=0 when timestamp=0. These data look right to me.

Anyone can shed light on this - why rawOffset could be different for EDINBURGH (just example of city)?

Thanks
Gary

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time), British Summer Time does not seems to exist after 1972. Which might explain why the day
[1971/5/31 12:00am](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=55.9066276551,-3.2620390298&timestamp=44496000) has a `"rawOffset" : 3600`

> {
>      "dstOffset" : 0,
>      "rawOffset" : 3600,
>      "status" : "OK",
>      "timeZoneId" : "Europe/London",
>      "timeZoneName" : "GMT+01:00"
>   }

While, one year after
[1972/5/31 12:00am](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=55.9066276551,-3.2620390298&timestamp=76118400), has a `"dstOffset" : 3600`

> {
>      "dstOffset" : 3600,
>      "rawOffset" : 0,
>      "status" : "OK",
>      "timeZoneId" : "Europe/London",
>      "timeZoneName" : "British Summer Time"
>   }

Comment: ok so looks like "rawOffset" does also include one hour summer time offset, if available,  and is not real "raw" time without any extra offset. I think that's probably the case and thanks for your answer!